# C++ Invalid arguments when using 'vector<> &'

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV library (v3.0.0) and trying to compile one [C++ project](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~gall/projects/houghforest/data/forest.tar.gz) with Eclipse 4.5.1.

I got an error:

```
Invalid arguments' Candidates are: 
void detectColor(?*, ?&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>&))'
```

(**update**: It really says '?' in the error message. The error message is shown after hitting "Build". I think I'm using Cross GCC compiler.)

`detectColor()` function is defined as:

```
void detectColor(IplImage *img, std::vector<IplImage*>& 
                 imgDetect, std::vector<float>& ratios);
```

and is called as:

```
void CRForestDetector::detectPyramid(IplImage *img, 
                                     vector<vector<IplImage*> >& vImgDetect,
                                     std::vector<float>& ratios) {
    IplImage* cLevel = cvCreateImage(...);
    for(int i=...; i<...; ++i) {
        detectColor(cLevel,vImgDetect[i],ratios);
    }    
}
```

How to solve this error?

(**update**: These kinds of errors disappeared after restart Eclipse.)

Comment: by `#include`ing appropriate headers? `#include <vector>` for `std::vector`. I can't help for `IplImage`. Google can.

Comment: you are mixing `vector` and `std::vector`. are you sure that they're the same (i.e. you did not include a different vector somewhere along the way)?

Comment: Does it really say `"?"` in the error message?! I've never seen that before. What compiler are you using? (Eclipse is not a compiler). Do you have some weird macro defined for `IplImage`?

Comment: I think the actual error message must give more information than that, probably large and barely readable, but it looks like that info is needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The most important thing is that you're still using **obsolete C syntax**. Please  use C++ api.

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler. Are you getting on-the-fly IDE messages that come and go as you type, or compiler messages after hitting "Build"?